# What is the "conventional" way of handling uploaded image names?

Tags: php, mysql, image-processing

So im making a website with an image upload functionality and im storing the image name to the database. I took a screenshot of my mac and wanted to upload this photo "Screen shot 2011-02-18 at 6.52.20 PM.png". Well, thats not a nice name to store in mysql! How do people ususally rename photos in such a way that each photo uploaded has a unique name? Also, how would i make sure i keep the file extension in the end when renaming the photo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would drop the extension, otherwise Apache (or equivalent) will run `a1e99398da6cf1faa3f9a196382f1fadc7bb32fb7.php` if requested (which may contain malicious PHP). I would also upload it to above the docroot.

If you need to to make the image accessible above the docroot, you can store a safe copy that is ran through image functions or serve it from some PHP with `header('Content-Type: image/jpeg')` for example and `readfile()` (**not** `include` because I can embed PHP in a GIF file).

Also, `pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)` is the best way to get an extension.

Ensure you have stored a reference to this file with original filename and other meta data in a database.

```
function getUniqueName($originalFilename) {
    return sha1(microtime() . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . $originalFilename);
}
```

The only way this can generate a duplicate is if one user with the same IP uploads the same filename more than once within a microsecond.

Alternatively, you could just use the `basename($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'])` that PHP assigns when you upload an image. I would say it should be unique.

Comment: what do you mean by "dropping the extension"? are you saying you would only store the hash value in mysql and not that hash + file extension?

Comment: I would store everything the user gave you in the database, but store the file itself on the server with a unique name with no extension.

Comment: but if its an image, and if you drop the extension, how would you know whether the image is a jpeg, gif, or png when accessing it?

Comment: +1 for thinking about security. Don't trust the extension the user gave. Make sure you use a valid extension like jpeg or png. Also, you should ALWAYS disable script access (e.g., .htaccess with Apache) in any directory that you place user uploaded files as the permissions are generally very liberal (g+w or u+w).

Comment: so just store the filename on the server, but store the filename + extension in the mysql table. interesting, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hash the image name. Could be md5, sha1 or even a unix timestamp.

Here is an (untested) example with a random number (10 to 99)

```
<?php
function generate_unique_name($file_name)
{
    $splitted = split(".", $file_name);
    return time() . rand(10,99) . "." . $splitted[count($splitted)-1];
}
?>
```

Comment: dont md5 and sha1 output 32 and 40 characters respective? Thats alot of characters for one image name...

Comment: Atleast it would be unique. Additionally, you could expand the unix timestamp, so you wont end up having two pictures of that name, if two persons submits at the same time.

Comment: I've seen a lot of unix timestamp + a random number. You can also use something like crc32 as well.

Comment: im not to familiar with php, how do you generate a random number again? And how would you maintain the .png extension if you were to unix timestamp it.

Comment: What if two files are uploaded at the same second and `rand()` returns the same random number and they have the same extension?

Comment: Use `md5` or `sha1` if you are hashing the image data itself. Otherwise, you may as well just come up with a string of (e.g.) 6 random alphanumeric characters. That's 2 billion unique names.

Comment: @konforce Would your recommend hashing the file contents as opposed to trying to generate a random filename? Is it safe to use the temporary name PHP assigns to uploaded files? Thanks.

Comment: @alex, depends on the context. If a site uses a lot of images, I like to have an abstract image table [id,filename (original),sha1_hash,size,format] that generates a hash based on the file contents. So if the same image is uploaded multiple times, it only gets stored once. I then have an image_id foreign link in other tables. The image may be resized, cropped, etc and stored in another location... perhaps with a random short filename. If the site only casually uses images, I'll just throw away the original, keep the resized version, and give it a short, unique random name.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an image table like:

```
id: int
filename: varchar 
hash: varchar
format: enum('jpeg', 'png')
```

The hash can be something like `sha1_file($uploaded_file)` and used to make sure duplicate images aren't uploaded. (So you could have multiple entries in the image table with the same hash, if you wanted.) The id is useful so you can have integer foreign key links back to the image table.

Next store the images in either:

```
/image/$id.$format
```

or

```
/image/$hash.$format
```

The second format via the hash would make sure you don't duplicate image data. If you are dealing with lots of images, you may want to do something like:

```
/image/a/b/c/abcdef12345.jpg
```

where you use multiple layers of folders to store the images. Many file systems get slowed down with too many files in a single directory.

Now you can link to those files directly, or set up a URL like:

```
/image/$id/$filename
```

For example:

```
/image/12347/foo.jpg
```

The `foo.jpg` comes from whatever the user uploaded. It is actually ignored because you look up via the id. However, it makes the image have a nice name if the person chooses to download it. (You may optionally validate that the image filename matches after you look up the id.)

The above path can be translated to image.php via Apache's MultiView or ModRewrite. Then you can `readfile()` or use X-SendFile (better performance, but not always available) to send the file to the user.

Note that if you don't have X-SendFile and don't want to process things through PHP, you could use a RewriteRule to convert `/image/$hash/foo.jpg` into `/image/a/b/c/$hash.jpg`.